# "Visual Lines" attribute for Long Text Area field doesn't do anything?

Tags: fields, long-text-area

I created a new field on a custom object, and when creating it, I have the option to specify the amount of visible lines:

[image]

But when I look at the object in SF, all the lines are displayed. Why is this? Am I misunderstanding what this option does?

Comment: this is the number of lines on the new/edit page

Comment: @cropredy and that should be an answer, not a comment. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`# Visible Lines` refers to the number of lines displayed for input (before scrolling) on the New/Edit page. As such it helps control the layout of the form and hints to the user how much data can be entered for the "normal" use case.

If the long text field has more than 3 lines of data (as in your example) - even if it has 1000+ lines of data, the detail page will show all the lines.

Comment: Is there a option that needs to be selected for this to work. I created two long text area fields one with 3 visible lines and one with 10 visible lines in a playground. I checked the detail page, the edit page and the create new record form and they both match with only 2 lines showing.

Comment: @eHarazi - You should post a new question with screen shots of what you observe